# Ensure an object with dynamic keys has at least one key with yup

Tags: yup

I use yup for validation. I want to ensure that an object with dynamic keys has at least one key. My code so far:

```
const propertySchema = object({
    emails: lazy(obj => {
        return object(
            mapValues(obj, () => object({
                email: string().required(),
                token: string().required(),
                tokenExpiresAt: number().integer().positive()
            }))
        )
    })
})

const user1 = {
  emails: { }
}


const user2 = {
  emails: {
    "some@mail.de": {
      email: 'some@mail.de'
      token: 'abcd'
      tokenExpiresAt: 4712
    }
  }
}

//this should fail
propertySchema.validateSync(user1)

//this should work
propertySchema.validateSync(user2)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [test](https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#validation-tests).

```
const min = 1;
const propertySchema = yup.object({
    emails: yup.lazy(obj => {
        return yup.object(
            mapValues(obj, () => yup.object({
                email: yup.string().required(),
                token: yup.string().required(),
                tokenExpiresAt: yup.number().integer().positive(),
            })),
        ).test({
            name: 'minKeys',
            params: {min},
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-template-curly-in-string
            message: '${path} must have min ${min} key(s)',
            test: (value) => value == null || Object.keys(value).length >= min,
        });
    }),
});

const user1 = {
    emails: {},
};

const user2 = {
    emails: {
        'some@mail.de': {
            email: 'some@mail.de',
            token: 'abcd',
            tokenExpiresAt: 4712,
        },
    },
};

console.log(propertySchema.validateSync(user2));
// {emails: {...}}
console.log(propertySchema.validateSync(user1));
// Uncaught ValidationError: emails must have 1 keys
```